# Recoverable Error when running OPNET project

Tags: networking, simulation, opnet

I'm new in studying and using OPNET14.5. I got a problem when running my project:
[image]

While running my project, it keeps throwing `<<< Recoverable Error >>>No field named (Type) in packet (XXXXX).` However, it seems that these problems doesn't affect the final simulation result, it just slows the simulation's speed.

So why these problems happened? How to solve them? Thanks.